# Setting the default value in a DataTextField for a SelectList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, selectlist

I am trying to change the default selection in a SelectList Constructor for a dropDownList, the selectList constructor allows for a third argument which is a string representing the value of the DataTextField for the selectList, but when I try either of the following:

```
new SelectList(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, Model.XXXX.xxxx, 3)
new SelectList(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, Model.XXXX.xxxx, "3")
```

I get an error:

> "The best overloaded method match has some invalid arguments"

What am I not understanding? It seems to me that the second of the above lines should work since I am giving it a third String argument to display in the DataTextField.

As a minor subquestion, what does the syntax

```
new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
```

mean? I am new to C# and brackets after the new keyword are foreign to me.

Comment: You set the initial selected option by binding to a model property. If you have a property (say) `Number` and you set its value to `3`, then using `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Number, new SelectList(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }))` will select the 3rd option. That's how model bind works.

Answer (score 2):

One of the overloads for the SelectList constructor is the following

```
SelectList(IEnumerable, String, String);
```

IEnumerable --> items for the list

String --> data value field

String --> data text field

You IEnumerable is `new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }` which is basically an array of integers with its elements as 1, 2, 3 and 4.

The data value field is your model, and the text field is "3".

If you are trying to create a select list from one of your models I would suggest that you do the following

```
new SelectList(Model, "Data Value field", "Data text field");
```

For Example:
If you have a student model (Std_ID,Std_Name), and you need a select list to show the student names and to hold the value of their ID

```
new SelectList(Model, "Std_ID", "Std_Name");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SelectList sl = new SelectList( new[]{
  new SelectListItem{ Text="one", Value="1"},
  new SelectListItem{ Text="two", Value="2"},
  new SelectListItem{ Text="three", Value="3"}
}, "Text", "Value", "3" );
```

To your another question,

> new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }

you are basically creating an array of int datatype with its elements as 1, 2, 3 and 4

Answer (score 0):

The constructor you are using for SelectList

```
public SelectList(
    IEnumerable items,
    string dataValueField,
    string dataTextField
)
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.)

When SelectList is rendered via your View, it's just HTML, so you should provide the anonymous array as string, dataValueField and dataTextField as string too.
Look in this context

```html
 <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="2">3</option>
      <option value="2">4</option>
  </select>
```

**Change your code as below**

```
new SelectList(new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4" }, Model.XXXX.xxxx, "3")
```

**Model.XXXX.xxxx** change it to your data value field.

```
new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 } // anonymous type by using the new operator with an object initializer. here this anonymous array is int type.
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb397696.aspx)

hope it helps.